# NextJs 13 - RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded - use server cookies().delete()

Tags: cookies, prisma, next.js13

I'm currently working on a authentification on NextJS 13. I'm trying to delete cookies from `next/headers`

```js
const handleLogOut = async () => {
  'use server'
  cookies().delete('user_data')
}

return <button onClick={ handleLogOut }>logout</button>
```

but when doing that I got a Maximum call stack exceed error. I also try with a `<a></a>`